# How to merge the api response in one single array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an api call to get the information of certain companies linked by the id of a client. Lets suppose that the api call is the next:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        await fetch('/api/myapi_where=clientId=' + idClient, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {              
              "Accept": "application",
              "Content-type": "application/json"
                },
            }).then(response => {
                 const hasInfo = response.json();
                   hasInfo.then(setInfo => {
                        console.log(setInfo)
                   })
                })
                .catch()
                })()
            },[])
```

On the response, the api has a promise, where lives the required information; that's why I need to transform the response on json format, an use "then". So, on the console log i see that there's more than one registers linked to the client. Per example, i have the next answer:

```
[{id:1, idClient: 2, name: "Company 1", creationDate: "2023-01-11"}]

[{id: 6, idClient: 2, name: "Company 2", creationDate: "2023-02-27"}] 

[{id: 25, idClient: 2, name: "Company 5", creationDate: "2023-03-10"}]
```

As you can see, on the database exists 3 different rows linked to a single client (idCLient 2). So, here's my question: how can I merge all this 3 different rows in a single array of objects? What i  wanna do is return the information on a single array to create a list with map. Something like this:

```
const singleArray = [{id:1, idClient: 2, name: "Company 1", creationDate: "2023-01-11"}, {id: 6, idClient: 2, name: "Company 2", creationDate: "2023-02-27"}, {id: 25, idClient: 2, name: "Company 5", creationDate: "2023-03-10"}]
```

And the list:

```
return (
  singleArray.map((info, index) => {
    return(
      <>
        <li key={index} className="class-name">
          <p>{info.name}</p>
      </>
    )
  })
)
```

I've already try with: `const someTest = setInfo.concat(setInfo);` and I receive:

```
[{id:1, idClient: 2, name: "Company 1", creationDate: "2023-01-11"}, {id:1, idClient: 2, name: "Company 1", creationDate: "2023-01-11"}, {id:1, idClient: 2, name: "Company 1", creationDate: "2023-01-11"}]
```

On a certain way, it's working, but not as I'm expecting. I receive 3 different arrays with the same information repeated 3 times (or X times, depending the length of the rows). Can you help me to fine the best practice to receive correctly the information as I need, please? I've been searching but cannot find something that realy helps me, or the correct way to get close to the solution. I'm working on react.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  [{id:1, idClient: 2, name: "Company 1", creationDate: "2023-01-11"}],
  [{id: 6, idClient: 2, name: "Company 2", creationDate: "2023-02-27"}],
  [{id: 25, idClient: 2, name: "Company 5", creationDate: "2023-03-10"}],
  [{id:2, idClient: 3, name: "Company 2", creationDate: "2023-01-11"}],
  [{id: 7, idClient: 3, name: "Company 3", creationDate: "2023-02-27"}],
  [{id: 26, idClient: 3, name: "Company 6", creationDate: "2023-03-10"}]
];

function App() {

  const clientData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const record = data[i][0];
    const clientIndex = clientData.findIndex((r) => r.idClient === record.idClient);
    if (clientIndex > -1) {
      clientData[clientIndex].data.push(record);
    } else {
      clientData.push({
        idClient: record.idClient,
        data: [record],
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
    {
      clientData.map((client) => {
        return (
          <div className="client-record">
            <span>Client ID: <b>#{client.idClient}</b></span>
            <span>Works at</span>
            {
              client.data.map((record) => {
                return (
                  <span>{record.name}</span>
                );
              })
            }
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.client-record {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the setInfo is array. In that case you can use the below method.
It will convert your array into array of objects.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        await fetch('/api/myapi_where=clientId=' + idClient, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {              
              "Accept": "application",
              "Content-type": "application/json"
                },
            }).then(response => {
                 const hasInfo = response.json();
                   hasInfo.then(setInfo => {
                    const result = setInfo.reduce((acc,item) => {
                      acc = [...acc, item[0]];
                      return acc;
                      },[])
                      console.log(result);
                   })
                })
                .catch()
                })()
            },[])
```